# Как создать float из четырех байтов?

Tags: java, float

У меня есть обработчик, где поступают 4 байта и они превращаются в int, но эта схема не работает с float, потому что нет по битового сдвига. Помогите изменить код. Надо 4 байта превратить во float

```
int int32 = 0;
int[] bytes = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
     bytes[i] = stream.get();
for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     int32 = (int32 << 8) | bytes[i];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Превратить массив байтов во `float` можно с помощью [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
byte[] data = { 10, 10, 10, 10 };
float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getFloat();
```

Если вместо big-endian порядка байтов нужен little-endian, то это нужно явно указать:

```
float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```

Answer (score 2):

Если требуется задать битовое представление для float, то это можно сделать на основе `int` с помощью [`Float.intBitsToFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)):

```
float value = Float.intBitsToFloat(int32);
```

Рекомендую предварительно уточнить, в каком порядке идут байты в исходном потоке.

Аналогичный вопрос на английском: [How to convert 4 bytes array to float in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469681/how-to-convert-4-bytes-array-to-float-in-java)